# How to think when saving application information (settings, data etc)?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, file

Been thinking about this some time: Let's say I have a application where you can add and use reminders.

What is the best way to store this? In the past I've always used a textfile but it can get problematic if I later want to add another "field" to each reminder in the textfile. Let's say I add an feature for recurring reminders.

What is the most volatile way? Text? Xml? Json? SQLite?

Comment: All of those ways work and all have different advantages and disadvantages. You will need to give more details if this is going to be a good Q&A question. Without details, this will be closed because everyone would just recommend their favorite way of saving information.

Comment: I agree w/ @nvoigt and are you sure you mean the most volatile way?

Comment: Possibly **opinion-based**.  _Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._

Answer (score 0):

Use a database.  Adding another field is as simple as adding another column to a table.
MySQL is a solid query language and easy to pick up for beginners.  When I started out, I watched (and really enjoyed) this tutorial series:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pbxQQG25Jw

If you ever make something that needs lots of scalability, you might want to look into PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite becomes a better option as your data model becomes more complex. The upgrade process (changing, adding, and removing tables) is a bit of work, and is required for your code to even refer to a new field in a query.

XML And JSON have the advantage of having parsers built into the standard libraries for most platforms these days, so you don't have to fix your parser every time you change your data model (as you would with plain text). XML can validate your model and let you know if the file does not comply with your model. JSON is really just a serialization protocol and doesn't provide anything in terms of model validation, which makes it the most flexible of the plain text options (IMO).

In terms of updating your model, your code should read in the file and allow for the new field to be missing or empty. If the field is mandatory, you should provide a default value and then write your model back out to the file so it's good to go the next time. This process is roughly the same for SQLite, but is just a bit more involved in terms of what you have to do to upgrade your model.